# My list of words as suggestions to search view

Tags: android, searchview

I have a list of words and a [`SearchView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SearchView.html).

When the user is typing a word, I want to suggest a list of words which starts with user entered characters. It is possible with Edittext, but how can I get it in `SearchView`?

Comment: Mr. Brontok's reply is quite helpful as for as your question is concerned but if you also want to save this list permanently then you should use the shared preferences

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this using **AutoCompleteTextView**

In your layout , use this

```
<AutoCompleteTextView
android:id="@+id/autocompletetextview"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="" >
</AutoCompleteTextView>
```

and use below code in your activity

```
AutoCompleteTextView autocompletetextview;

    String[] array = { "One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six", "Seven",
            "Eight", "Nine", "Ten" };

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        autocompletetextview = (AutoCompleteTextView)     findViewById(R.id.autocompletetextview);

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.select_dialog_item, array);

        autocompletetextview.setThreshold(1);

        autocompletetextview.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an `AutoCompleteTextView` instead. Here is the link to the [docs.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.html)